# VueJs [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am getting this error but in search console I am only getting
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"

When I go to check what line the error is coming from,it only highlights the first line where the variable is being initiated "var shoppingCartApp = new Vue({"

Is there a way of debugging this to show me which line 'title' is on?

Is there another reason I am getting this error?

```
<style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #shoppingCartApp {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 800px;
        margin: auto;
    }
    button:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        background: #B7053F !important;
    }
</style>

<div id="shoppingCartApp">

    <!-- First Page -->
    <div id="scPage-1">
        <div class="text-center">
            <h1>{{ mainTitle }}</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- Promo Code Section -->
        <div class="scPromoCode text-center">
            <input type="text" v-model="userPackageContent.promoCodeValue" /><button v-on:click="showPromoValue(userPackageContent.promoCodeValue)">Apply</button>
        </div>
        <!-- End Promo Code Section -->
        <br />
        <!-- Country Selection Section -->
        <div class="scCountries row text-center">
            <button class="usaButton col-sm" v-on:click="showUsaPrice()">USA</button>
            <button class="canButton col-sm" v-on:click="showCanPrice()">Canada</button>
            <select class="intButton col-sm" id="scCountryDropdown" name="country" v-on:click="showIntPrice()">
                <option value="International">International</option>
                <option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
                <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <!-- End Country Selection Section -->
        <br />
        <!-- Subscription Selection Section -->
        <div class="scJournalSelections row text-center">
            <div class="dailySubscription col-sm">
                <h2>{{ subscriptionInfo.dailySubcription.title }}</h2>
                <h2>${{ subscriptionInfo.dailySubcription.price }}</h2>
                <button v-on:click="getCurrentSubscriptionChoice($event)" value="Daily">Subscribe</button>
            </div>
            <div class="journalSubscription col-sm">
                <h2>{{ subscriptionInfo.journalSubcription.title }}</h2>
                <h2>${{ subscriptionInfo.journalSubcription.price }}</h2>
                <button v-on:click="getCurrentSubscriptionChoice($event)" value="Journal">Subscribe</button>
            </div>
            <div class="dualSubscription col-sm">
                <h2>{{ subscriptionInfo.dualSubcription.title }}</h2>
                <h2>${{ subscriptionInfo.dualSubcription.price }}</h2>
                <button v-on:click="getCurrentSubscriptionChoice($event)" value="Daily & Journal">Subscribe</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Subscription Selection Section -->
    </div>
    <!-- End First Page -->

    <div id="scPage-2" class="text-center">
        <h1>Login/Registration Page If Not Already Logged In</h1>
    </div>


    <div id="scPage-3" class="text-center">
        <h1>Delivery Address</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="scPage-4" class="text-center">
        <h1>Cart Details</h1>
        <div class="scPromoCode text-center">
            <input type="text" v-model="userPackageContent.promoCodeValue" /><button v-on:click="showPromoValue(userPackageContent.promoCodeValue)">Apply</button>
        </div>
        <p>Subscription: {{ userPackageContent.subscriptionChoiceTitle }}</p>
        <p>Promo Discount: {{ userPackageContent.promoDiscount }}</p>
    </div>

    <div id="scPage-5" class="text-center">
        <h1>Checkout</h1>
        <p>Total: ${{ userPackageContent.checkoutTotal }}</p>
        <p>Total: ${{ userPackageContent.salesTax }}</p>
    </div>

</div>







    <script>
        var shoppingCartApp = new Vue({
            el: '#shoppingCartApp',
            data: {
                mainTitle: 'Shopping Cart',
                //Promo Discount Information
                promoValidation: true,
                usaProps: {
                    promoCode: 'usa',
                    promoDiscount: 50,
                    subscriptionPrice: 2,
                    value: false
                },
                canProps: {
                    promoCode: 'can',
                    promoDiscount: 75,
                    subscriptionPrice: 4,
                    value: false
                },
                intProps: {
                    promoCode: 'int',
                    promoDiscount: 100,
                    subscriptionPrice: 6,
                    value: false
                },
                dualProps: {
                    promoCode: 'dual',
                    promoDiscount: 150,
                    subscriptionPrice: 8,
                    value: false
                },
                //Package Information
                subscriptionInfo: {
                    dailySubscription: {
                        price: 100,
                        title: 'Daily'
                    },
                    journalSubscription: {
                        price: 200,
                        title: 'Journal'
                    },
                    dualSubscription: {
                        price: 300,
                        title: 'Daily & Journal'
                    }
                },
                //User Checkout Information
                userPackageContent: {
                    subscriptionChoiceTitle: null,
                    subscriptionChoicePrice: null,
                    promoCodeValue: null,
                    promoDiscount: 0,
                    salesTax: 0,
                    checkoutTotal: null
                }

            },
            methods: {
                getCurrentSubscriptionChoice: function (e) {
                    var subscriptionValue = e.target.value;


                    if (subscriptionValue == this.subscriptionInfo.dailySubcription.title) {
                        this.userPackageContent.subscriptionChoiceTitle = this.subscriptionInfo.dailySubcription.title;
                        this.userPackageContent.subscriptionChoicePrice = this.subscriptionInfo.dailySubcription.price;
                        this.userPackageContent.checkoutTotal = this.userPackageContent.subscriptionChoicePrice;
                    }
                    if (subscriptionValue == this.subscriptionInfo.journalSubcription.title) {
                        this.userPackageContent.subscriptionChoiceTitle = this.subscriptionInfo.journalSubcription.title;
                        this.userPackageContent.subscriptionChoicePrice = this.subscriptionInfo.journalSubcription.price;
                        this.userPackageContent.checkoutTotal = this.userPackageContent.subscriptionChoicePrice;
                    }
                    if (subscriptionValue == this.subscriptionInfo.dualSubcription.title) {
                        this.userPackageContent.subscriptionChoiceTitle = this.subscriptionInfo.dualSubcription.title;
                        this.userPackageContent.subscriptionChoicePrice = this.subscriptionInfo.dualSubcription.price;
                        this.userPackageContent.checkoutTotal = this.userPackageContent.subscriptionChoicePrice;
                    }
                    console.log(this.userPackageContent.subscriptionChoiceTitle)
                    console.log(this.userPackageContent.subscriptionChoicePrice)

                },
                showCurrentCountrySelection: function () {
                    if (this.usaProps.value == true) {
                        $('.usaButton').css('background', 'rgba(171, 183, 183, 1)')
                    } else {
                        $('.usaButton').css('background', '#fff')
                    }
                    if (this.canProps.value == true) {
                        $('.canButton').css('background', 'rgba(171, 183, 183, 1)')
                    } else {
                        $('.canButton').css('background', '#fff')
                    }
                    if (this.intProps.value == true) {
                        $('.intButton').css('background', 'rgba(171, 183, 183, 1)')
                    } else {
                        $('.intButton').css('background', '#fff')
                    }
                },
                subscriptionChangePriceReset: function () {
                    this.subscriptionInfo.dailySubscription.price = 100;
                    this.subscriptionInfo.journalSubscription.price = 200;
                    this.subscriptionInfo.dualSubscription.price = 300;

                    this.promoValidation = true;
                },
                showPromoValue: function (value) {
                    if (value == "usa") {
                        if (this.usaProps.value == true && promoValidation) {
                            this.subscriptionInfo.dailySubscription.price = this.subscriptionInfo.dailySubscription.price - this.usaProps.promoDiscount;
                            this.subscriptionInfo.journalSubscription.price = this.subscriptionInfo.journalSubscription.price - this.usaProps.promoDiscount;
                            this.subscriptionInfo.dualSubscription.price = this.subscriptionInfo.dualSubscription.price - this.usaProps.promoDiscount;

                            this.promoValidation = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (value == "can") {
                        if (this.canProps.value == true && promoValidation) {
                            this.subscriptionInfo.dailySubscription.price = this.subscriptionInfo.dailySubscription.price - this.canProps.promoDiscount;
                            this.subscriptionInfo.journalSubscription.price = this.subscriptionInfo.journalSubscription.price - this.canProps.promoDiscount;
                            this.subscriptionInfo.dualSubscription.price = this.subscriptionInfo.dualSubscription.price - this.canProps.promoDiscount;

                            this.promoValidation = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (value == "int") {
                        if (this.int == true && promoValidation) {
                            this.subscriptionInfo.dailySubscription.price = this.subscriptionInfo.dailySubscription.price - this.intProps.promoDiscount;
                            this.subscriptionInfo.journalSubscription.price = this.subscriptionInfo.journalSubscription.price - this.intProps.promoDiscount;
                            this.subscriptionInfo.dualSubscription.price = this.subscriptionInfo.dualSubscription.price - this.intProps.promoDiscount;

                            this.promoValidation = false;
                        }
                    }
                },
                showUsaPrice: function () {
                    this.subscriptionChangePriceReset();
                    //Used to prevent promo code from constantly being applied
                    this.usaProps.value = true;
                    this.canProps.value = false;
                    this.intProps.value = false;

                    this.showCurrentCountrySelection();

                    this.subscriptionInfo.dailySubscription.price = this.subscriptionInfo.dailySubscription.price * this.usaProps.price; //API PRICE GOES HERE
                    this.subscriptionInfo.journalSubscription.price = this.subscriptionInfo.journalSubscription.price * this.usaProps.price; //API PRICE GOES HERE
                    this.subscriptionInfo.dualSubscription.price = this.subscriptionInfo.dualSubscription.price * this.usaProps.price; //API PRICE GOES HERE
                },
                showCanPrice: function () {
                    this.subscriptionChangePriceReset();
                    //Used to prevent promo code from constantly being applied
                    this.usaProps.value = false;
                    this.canProps.value = true;
                    this.intProps.value = false;

                    this.showCurrentCountrySelection();

                    this.subscriptionInfo.dailySubscription.price = this.subscriptionInfo.dailySubscription.price * this.canProps.price; //API PRICE GOES HERE
                    this.subscriptionInfo.journalSubscription.price = this.subscriptionInfo.journalSubscription.price * this.canProps.price; //API PRICE GOES HERE
                    this.subscriptionInfo.dualSubscription.price = this.subscriptionInfo.dualSubscription.price * this.canProps.price; //API PRICE GOES HERE
                },
                showIntPrice: function () {
                    this.subscriptionChangePriceReset();
                    //Used to prevent promo code from constantly being applied
                    this.usaProps.value = false;
                    this.canProps.value = false;
                    this.intProps.value = true;

                    this.showCurrentCountrySelection();

                    this.subscriptionInfo.dailySubscription.price = this.subscriptionInfo.dailySubscription.price * this.intProps.price; //API PRICE GOES HERE
                    this.subscriptionInfo.journalSubscription.price = this.subscriptionInfo.journalSubscription.price * this.intProps.price; //API PRICE GOES HERE
                    this.subscriptionInfo.dualSubscription.price = this.subscriptionInfo.dualSubscription.price * this.intProps.price; //API PRICE GOES HERE
                }
            }
        })

        console.log("Script running")
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check data before getting a deep value of `title`.

So try something like this:

```
if (subscriptionValue == this.subscriptionInfo &&
 this.subscriptionInfo.dailySubcription &&
 this.subscriptionInfo.dailySubcription.title)
```

Also, in your component do:

```
{{ subscriptionInfo.dailySubcription && subscriptionInfo.dailySubcription.title }}
```

Just Change in all places where you have deep values and this should work.

Some helpful links: [link-1](https://css-tricks.com/%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8Bavoiding-those-dang-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-errors/), [link-2](https://dev.to/tbetous/how-to-safely-access-deep-nested-values-in-javascript-5b2a).

Comment: Thank you for this and the references. I changed this for both the title and the price and the error has been resolved but the values are still not showing for me. I will read through the links you have given me and see what I can do from here!

Comment: Ok, did you check carefully for typos?

Comment: after tons of reading and trying.....yes...it was a typo lol thanks!

Comment: You are welcome if the answer solved your error, can you please mark it as answer. Thanks.